# Rails 4 ActiveRecord append conditions (multiple .where)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I would like to append `AND` conditions depend on condition like this:

```
@flag = true || false;

@results = Model.where(conditions).where(conditions_depend_on_flag);
```

// The simple way:

```
if (@flag) {
    @results = Model.where(conditions);
} else {
    @results = Model.where(conditions).where(conditions_depend_on_flag);
}
```

Example for my expected:

```
@results = Model.where(conditions).where(conditions_depend_on_flag, @flag == true);
```

I don't know is it possible or not.

Could you give me some suggestion?

Answer (score 4):

```
@results = Model.where(conditions)
@results = @results.where(conditions_depend_on_flag) if @flag
```

Comment: Does this run 2 separated queries?

Comment: No, it just creates a relation.

Answer (score 0):

We can combine 2 conditions into 1 where statement:

To make it easy I assume:

```
conditions                = created_at < 1.day.ago
conditions_depend_on_flag = updated_at > 1.day.ago
```

So the query will be:

```
Model.where(
    'created_at < ? AND (? OR updated_at > ?)', 1.day.ago, !@flag, 1.day.ago
)
```

Beautiful SQL :)

Answer (score 0):

use scopes for sql conditions

in model

```
scope :conditions_depend_on_flag, ->(flag) { where(....) if flag }
```

anywhere

```
@results = Model.where(conditions).conditions_depend_on_flag(@flag)
```